# How do I delete an item from my cart adapter?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am using ArrayAdapter When I delete the first item from Listview.Its delete perfectly.But When I do delete the second item from the listview. Its not perfectly delete.
how can i do it?

Adapter coding

```
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; 
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // final CartBean beans = getItem(position);

    View view = convertView;
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_cart_row, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.row_price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_price);
        viewHolder.et_quantity = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.cart_quantity);
        viewHolder.row_item_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_item_name);
        viewHolder.deleteButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_delete);
        //  viewHolder.rastaurantoffer = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.rastaurantname2);


        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (viewHolder.textWatcher != null)
        viewHolder.et_quantity.removeTextChangedListener(viewHolder.textWatcher);
    final CartBean bean = getItem(position);
    viewHolder.textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            if (charSequence.length()>0) {
                viewHolder.row_price.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(Double.parseDouble(bean.getTotal_price()) * Integer.parseInt(charSequence.toString()))));
                AppConstants.cartBeanArrayList.get(position).setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(charSequence.toString()));

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            Double totalPrice=0.0;
            for (int i=0;i<AppConstants.cartBeanArrayList.size();i++)
            {
               totalPrice=totalPrice+(Double.parseDouble(AppConstants.cartBeanArrayList.get(i).getTotal_price()) * AppConstants.cartBeanArrayList.get(i).getQuantity());
                Log.i("total_price12356",""+total_price);
            }
            ActivityCart.tv_sub_total.setText("£. "+String.valueOf(df.format(totalPrice)));
        }
    };
        viewHolder.row_price.setText("£."+String.valueOf(df.format(Double.parseDouble(cartBeans.get(position).getTotal_price()) * cartBeans.get(position).getQuantity())));
        viewHolder.et_quantity.setText(String.valueOf(cartBeans.get(position).getQuantity()));
        viewHolder.row_item_name.setText(cartBeans.get(position).getItem_name());
        viewHolder.et_quantity.addTextChangedListener(viewHolder.textWatcher);
         if(isDeleteRequired){
        viewHolder.deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.et_quantity.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        viewHolder.et_quantity.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        viewHolder.et_quantity.setCursorVisible(true);
        viewHolder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                AppConstants.cartBeanArrayList.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                for (int i = 0; i < AppConstants.cartBeanArrayList.size(); i++) {
                   //  String price = AppConstants.cartBeanArrayList.get(i).getTotal_price().substring(3, AppConstants.cartBeanArrayList.get(i).getTotal_price().length());
                   // Log.i("total_price123",""+price);
                    total_price = total_price + ActivityCart.getTotal(i);
                    Log.i("total_price123",""+total_price);
                    Log.i("total_price1237",""+AppConstants.cartBeanArrayList.size());
               //     AppConstants.cartBeanArrayList.clear();

                }

                Log.i("total_price1234",""+total_price);
                ActivityCart.tv_sub_total.setText("£. "+String.valueOf(total_price));
                if (AppConstants.cartBeanArrayList.size()==0)
                {
                    ActivityCart.tv_sub_total.setText("£.0.00");
                }
               // AppConstants.addressBeanArrayList.setText(String.valueOf(total_price));
            }
        });

    }else{
        viewHolder.deleteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return view;
}

class ViewHolder {

    TextView row_item_name;
    TextView row_price;
    EditText et_quantity;
    ImageView deleteButton;
    public TextWatcher textWatcher;

}

public void setIsDeleteRequired(boolean isDeleteRequire){
    isDeleteRequired = isDeleteRequire;
}
}
```

And getTotal() method coding is:

```
public static Double getTotal(int i) {
    total   =(Double.parseDouble(AppConstants.cartBeanArrayList.get(i).getTotal_price()) * AppConstants.cartBeanArrayList.get(i).getQuantity());
    Log.i("totalsunder", "" +total);
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Exactly where u get problem ?

Comment: @NiravRanpara I get problem in total price.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got the answer myself.

**Here my code**

```
       viewHolder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                AppConstants.cartBeanArrayList.remove(position);


                for (int i = 0; i < AppConstants.cartBeanArrayList.size(); i++) {


                    total_price = total_price + ActivityCart.getTotal(i);



                }


                ActivityCart.tv_sub_total.setText("£. "+String.valueOf(total_price));
total_price =0.0;
             notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//removing from database
                int i =impl_cart.deleteRow(data_cart.get(position).get_id());
//removing from adapter
                data_cart.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });
```